# Custom attribute are not showing in product collection in external file in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I am getting product collection from external php file like below-

```
<?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
//Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::init('default');
Mage::app('default');



$productCollection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(169);
var_dump( $productCollection->getHidemrp());
```

Hidemrp is "yes/no" type custom  attribute.

But I am not getting any value ? what is the problem.?

Comment: have you assigned attributes set or product in admin end?

Comment: @abdul Yes I did that

Comment: have you created in admin end and set Scope : Global or Store View r Website?